# ¿Cómo puedo hacer este codigo en asíncrono?

Tags: javascript, async

Tengo este codigo de javascript, ¿cómo lo puedo hacer asíncrono?

```js
setInterval(function() {
    fetch('https://cors.mixerno.space/https://www.brick-hill.com/forum/', {
        headers: {
            'origin': 'null'
        }
    }).then(res => res.text()).then(data => {
        forums = data;
    })
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Hola Shigero Toura, recuerda darle un vistazo al apartado de [ask]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

En mi experiencia me eh encontrado con varios problemas usando promesas, ya que en algunas ocasiones puedes llegar a perder el alcance de cierta funciones, usar `async await` es una buena opción para lidiar con dichos problemas, aunque puedes tener algunos problemas de compatibilidad con algunos navegadores al usar `async await`, primero que nada, veo que estas usando `fetch` para consumir una api, en mi opinión te recomendaría que uses `axios`, ya que puedes configurarlo para tener un mayor manejo de las peticiones, como dije, es simplemente una recomendacion, yendo al grano, a tu funcion la escribiria de la siguiente manera,

```
setInterval(async () => {
   try{
      const response = await fetch('https://cors.mixerno.space/https://www.brick-hill.com/forum/',{ headers: { 'origin': 'null' } })
      console.log(response)
   }catch(error){
      throw new Error(error)
   }
}, 5000);
```

lo que haces con este código es muy fácil de leer, simplemente se esta ejecutando cada 5 segundos una función, dicha función contiene un `try catch`, dicho método ayuda mucho a la hora de trabajar con código asíncrono, dentro del `try` se ejecuta la petición, una vez la petición haya terminado, el resultado se guarda en una constante `response` y a continuación se muestra en consola el resultado, seguro te preguntaras, que hace el `throw new Error(error)`, esto simplemente lo que hace es que si ocurre algún error dentro del `try`, este `catch` captura ese error y simplemente en este caso lo muestras por consola, siéntete libre de establecer tu propia lógica para manejar tus errores, espero te sirva de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Gracias! La explicacion fue clara! No me esperaba que fuera tan sencillo. Te lo agradezco!

Comment: para lo que necesites, saludoss

Answer (score -1):

Justo en la deficición de la función. Lo puedes hacer asincrona aún cuando la función es anónima.

```
setInterval(async function() {
    await fetch('https://cors.mixerno.space/https://www.brick-hill.com/forum/', {
        headers: {
            'origin': 'null'
        }
    }).then(res => res.text()).then(data => {
        forums = data;
    })
}, 5000);
```

Más información [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona)

Comment: Pero, ¿qué sentido tiene usar await si vas a obtener el resultado a través de la promesa?

Comment: La diferencia es que con el await va a esperar a resolver la peticion para trabajar el then; mientras sin el continuara las instrucciones despues de la promesa aún si resolver la petición. Si la petición es muy cargada te evitará tener una cola de peticiones.

Answer (score -1):

Para transformar ese código asíncrono y evitar la cadena de promesas lo podrías realizar de la siguiente manera:

```
setInterval(async function() {
    const request = await fetch('https://cors.mixerno.space/https://www.brick-hill.com/forum/');
    const forum = await request.json();
}, 5000);
```

Cualquier función, sea anónima o no, puede ser asíncrona, siendo así, al definir una función como `async`, podemos utilizar `await` dentro del cuerpo de esta, entonces;

```
// Esperamos que la petición sea realizada
const request = await fetch('https://cors.mixerno.space/https://www.brick-hill.com/forum/');

// Resolvemos la promesa de manera asíncrona 
// evitando el then(() => {}) que tienes actualmente
// esperando por la respuesta que nos entregará la petición
const forum = await request.json();
```